# How to make the column widths dynamic in docx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I have written a pronunciation guide for a foreign language. It has information about each word in a list. I want to use docx to show the pronunciation guide above the original words and the part of speech below the words.

The length of the text between each word varies considerably, as does the difference in length between the pronunciation, word, and part of speech as shown below.

`docx` forces me to specify a column width, i.e. `Inches(.25)`  when I add a column using `table.add_column(Inches(.25)).cells`.  I tried playing with the `autofit` object listed [here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html) and could not figure out what it actually does.

The desired result looks like this:

```
pronunciation_1 | pronunciation_2 | pronunciation_3
---------------------------------------------------
word_1          | word_2          | word_3
---------------------------------------------------
part_of_speech_1 | part_of_speech_2|part_of_speech_3
```

Here's a code example of my attempt to get this to work. I have tried several times solve my questions below but the code I've written either crashes or returns results worse than this:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
document = Document()
table = document.add_table(rows=3,cols=0)
word_1 = ['This', "th is", 'pronoun']
word_2 = ['is', ' iz', 'verb']
word_3 = ['an', 'uh n', 'indefinite article']
word_4 = ['apple.','ap-uh l', 'noun']
my_word_collection = [word_1,word_2,word_3,word_4]
for word in my_word_collection:
    my_word = word[0]
    pronunciation = word[1]
    part_of_speech = word[2]
    column_cells = table.add_column(Inches(.25)).cells
    column_cells[0].text = pronunciation
    column_cells[1].text = my_word
    column_cells[2].text = part_of_speech
document.save('my_word_demo.docx')
```

Here's what the results look like.  This is a screenshot of how my code renders the text in MS Word:
[image: Code rendered in MS Word showing non-dynamic cell widths]

My specific question is:

**How can you make the column widths dynamic?**

I want the column width to adjust to the longest of the three data points for each word (my_word, pronunciation, or part_of_speech) to that none of the text needs to wrap, and also so there's not unnecessary excessive space around each word.  The goal is the document is created and the reader/user doesn't have to adjust the cell widths for it to be readable.

If it helps, the Q/A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43053996/3225420) says cell width must be set individually.  I tried Googling around how to calculate character widths but it seems like there would be a way to handle this in docx that I don't know about.

Comment: What results does `table.autofit = True` produce for you?

Comment: @scanny I tried adding this code and running in three different spots: immediately after table creation, inside the loop, and just before saving the document - I could see no difference between having it and not, the same results as pictured in my question were returned.

Comment: Well, this setting is not "acted upon" until rendering time, so anytime after table creation is fine and once is all you need. I see that you set the column width on each new one you add, which is the only option for whatever historical reason (width is a required parameter). Does it behave better if you "pre-allocate" your columns at table creation time? It's possible the width value is overriding the auto-fit behavior.